# Is it possible to find Tensional force from Lagrangian?

Tags: forces, lagrangian-formalism, free-body-diagram, string

The Lagrangian principle is easier to solve than any kind of problem. But, we always "forget" (not really, but we don't take it into account directly), of Tension in a system when looking at Lagrangian. But, some questions say to find Tension. Since we can get the equation of motion from Newton's 2nd law (where lots of force are taken into account, with too messy an equation). Then, can we get only tension force from the equation of motion, without looking at Newton's 2nd law.

Let's think of simple pulley system with two mass on hanging on rope (figure attached below), rope and pulley itself has no mass.

[image]

The Lagrangian for the system is $$L=\frac{1}{2}m_1 \dot x^2+\frac{1}{2}m_2 \dot x^2 +m_1 gx+m_2 g (l-x)$$ (Ignore constraint in the figure. They will give the same result but I am ignoring subscripts)

But if the question directly says to find Tension, can I reach to tension from the Lagrangian? (I would like to apply a method which works for all systems not only above ones)

Comment: Cross-posted in [PF](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/is-it-possible-to-find-tensional-force-from-lagrange.1016372/)